# TextField to DatePicker in lwuit

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

how do I convert a TextField to a DatePicker using calendar?

please provide me an example

Answer (score 2):

Currently Its not possible with LWUIT. But you can use [`Spinner`](http://www.lwuit.com/2009/12/spinning-it-round-and-round.html) instead of `DatePicker`.

Comment: Look on this third party application for [`DateField` on LWUIT.](http://sites.google.com/site/franciscobenitezleon/projects/lwuit-datefield)  May be it will helps you.

Comment: THIS PROJECT IS CURRENTLY ABANDONED!

Comment: Yeah. But you can checkout from their [SVN path.](http://df4lwuit.svn.sourceforge.net/) You can go through how to they with do. If you need, build that project and use that JAR file into your application.